# Is it possible to control the URL for an Elastic Beanstalk instance when using eb create?

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I use `eb create` to create a new Elastic Beanstalk environment as so:

```
eb create myappbeta
```

...the resulting URL contains an auto-generated part:

```
myappbeta-epjmudtzjs.elasticbeanstalk.com
```

When I create the environment through the Web console I get the chance to control the URL, so I can just have:

```
myappbeta.elasticbeanstalk.com
```

Is there any way to do this using `eb create`?

My `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` is:

```
branch-defaults:
  default:
    environment: myappprod
deploy:
  artifact: myapp/target/scala-2.10/myapp_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
global:
  application_name: myapp
  default_ec2_keyname: abc
  default_platform: 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.4 running Tomcat 7 Java 7
  default_region: us-east-1
  profile: null
  sc: null
```

I have also tried with a CNAME setting in a saved configuration:

```
CName: myappbeta
```

But still it doesn't work... and generates an auto generated part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `eb create --cname <CNAME_PREFIX>` to control the CNAME for your environment.

Reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-create.html

Comment: Yep, this works with ONLY the `--cname` argument specified. What I didn't realise was that if I give an environment name, the CNAME gets that suffix. Thanks.